# Meromorphic function can be represented by a rational function

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Let $z_1,...,z_n\in \mathbb{C}$ and $f: \mathbb{C}\setminus \{z_1,...,z_n\} \to \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic. Furthermore, $\operatorname{ord}(f,z_i)$ is finite for all $i$ and $\lim\limits_{|z|\to\infty}f(z)=0$. prove that $f$ is a rational function.

Taking a look at the main parts of the Laurent series expansion in $z_i$ might be helpful, but I don't know how to complete the proof.

Comment: $g(z) := f(z)\prod_{1\le j \le n} (z - z_i)^{\operatorname{ord}(f,z_i)}$ is an entire function bounded above by a polynomial growth ..

Comment: Show that a meromorphic function on $\mathbb C$ with a finite amount of poles is a sum of rational functions and an entire function. Then use Liouville to show that the entire function is also rational if $\lim_{\vert z\vert\to\infty}f(z)=0$.